# Not able to add user to phpMyadmin hosted on localHost web server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to host MySQL on a local Web Host there is suppossed to be a previleges button where ic an add my Users which apparently appears in the one i hosted in my System .But dosent appear in the one i hosted on web .I am not getting the option of adding the user here.I checked through websites but all say click on the previleges button which dosent appear for me.

Here is my Screen

[image]

Comment: Do you have root privileges ?

Comment: I dont think so cuz its not visible here